# How to pass class instance as parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form` class:

```
public partial class Capture : Form
{    

    private DisplayError _displayError;

    public Capture(DisplayError displayError)
    {
        _displayError = displayError;
    }

    private OtherMethod()
    {
        _displayError("string with error");
    }
}
```

And `DisplayError` class (both are in the same `namespace`):

```
public class DisplayError
{
    public DialogResult ShowErrorBox(string error)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(error, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I have an error

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'displayError' of 'Capture.Capture(DisplayError)'
```

on line `Application.Run(new Capture());`

How'd I load `DisplayError` instance as `Capture` parameter?

Comment: With another `new`?

Comment: Did `Application.Run(new Capture(new DisplayError()));` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is a question, but the constructor is for parameters that are required when the form instance is created. So when newing up an instance you need to pass the parameter.

```
Application.Run(new Capture(new DisplayError()));
```